# push consecutives ubytes in asm

Tags: assembly

Well, in assembly is not possible push a unsigned byte; we need push a word (extend the sign).

I can do "push 0x0b00c8f0", but I need create the dword per separate. I can say, I need push 0b, after 00, after c8 and after f0. Once this 4 push done, I need form the dword with these bytes.

I have:

```
push WORD 0x0b
push WORD 0x00
push WORD 0xc8
push WORD 0xf0
push 0x11111111
movsb [esp], [esp+4]
movsb [esp+1], [esp+8]
movsb [esp+2], [esp+12]
movsb [esp+3], [esp+16]
; Now esp = 0x0b00c8f0
```

But ESP can not separate in a 8-bit segment, so, how can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand your requirements here. You say "but I need create the dword per separate." Why does this need to be separate? You say "I need form the dword with these bytes," but you already know what the dword is (0x0b00c8f0).  Why form it again? "ESP can not separate in a 8-bit segment" but you just built [esp] from the individual bytes, why are you trying to separate things out again? `movsb [esp], [esp+4]` doesn't actually compile, does it? Maybe if you could describe your final goal here, someone could suggest some steps to get there. What you have so far doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example doesn't work since a x86-processor has no "memory to memory move". But you can treat the stack like a normal memory (without `push`):

```
sub esp, 4
mov BYTE [esp], 0xf0
mov BYTE [esp+1], 0xc8
mov BYTE [esp+2], 0x00
mov BYTE [esp+3], 0x0b
```